Every day, how much speed does Voyager lose due to the sun's gravity?
The Voyager spacecraft will never be pulled back into the sun because it achieved escape velocity. But it's moving away slower and slower all the time.
Voyager is currently moving away from us at 31,000 mph.
Every day, how many MPH does voyager slow down?

Illustration: kind courtesy of NASA/JPL
It's so far away that it can't be much.

Of order 1 cm/sec per day (est.), but...
We can use some basic physics to estimate this number.
The distance and speed of Voyager 1 are 2.475E+13 meters and 16,885 m/s. For Voyager 2 those are 2.069E+13 m and 15,044 m/s.
The specific kinetic and potential energies (i.e. drop the masses of the Voyagers since they're so small compared to that of the Sun) are
$$T = \frac{v^2}{2}$$
$$U = -\frac{G m_{Sun}}{r} $$
Their total specific energies $E = T + U$ should stay essentially constant.
$$2E = v^2 - \frac{2 G m_{Sun}}{r}$$
$$v^2 = 2E + \frac{2 G m_{Sun}}{r}$$
$$v = \left(2E + \frac{2 G m_{Sun}}{r}\right)^{1/2}$$
$$\frac{dv}{dr} = \frac{1}{2} \left(2E + \frac{2 G m_{Sun}}{r}\right)^{-1/2} \ \frac{-2 G m_{Sun}}{r^2}$$
The standard gravitational parameter of the Sun (the product $G m_{Sun}$ is about 1.327E+20 m3/s3
With the simplifying assumption that since they are now so far away that they are moving nearly directly away from the Sun in a radial direction (I did say "estimate"!) we can use $86400 \times v$ for $dr$ in meters per day, and get $dv$ values for Voyagers 1 and 2 of -1.9 and -2.7 cm/sec per day.
How close are those estimates?
The problem with the concept of velocity (speed actually) is that we always have to ask "With respect to what?"
We're talking about tiny changes here. Jupiter and Neptune (primarily) do a gravitational dance with the Sun, so the speed of the Voyagers in neither Heliocentric nor Barycentric coordinates will always be comparable to those numbers.
If we look at the rates of change of the heliocentric and barycentric radial velocities (deltadots) or what I call "deltadoubledots", we see that while the values are the right magnitude (order cm/sec/day) the reality is more complicated.
The 12.6 year period of Jupiter's effect on the Sun's barycentric velocity is clear. Neptune's effect on the Sun's barycentric velocity changes too gradually to make visible oscillations within a mere century.
Now why the heck Voyager 2's heliocentric radial velocity will keep increasing until 2029 is a mystery to me. I'll try more coffree, and if that doesn't work, I'll ask a new, separate question.
I suppose it's related to the fact that it's not actually moving radially, so the radial speed is not a good proxy for total speed.
JPL Horizons Observer ephemeris:


If the question had been what is the slowdown in respect to the Sun, would it just be the basic acceleration formula of 1.327E+20 / the distance from the Sun squared. Using 24.87 billion km (24.87 trillion meters) for Voyager 1 I get 2.146E-07 m/sec/sec  or 0.03 cm/sec/day. For Voyager 2 at 20.78 billion km I get 0.04 cm/sec/day.

"it's not actually moving radially, so the radial speed is not a good proxy for total speed". This. The "range" speed is increasing, but if you calculate the tangential speed of the trajectory it's decreasing like we'd expect.

Here are 3 year plots of the tangential speed of each Voyager relative to the SSB, with a 7 day timestep. I posted the plot for Voyager 1 earlier in a comment on Ludo's answer. https://i.sstatic.net/2c8CyCM6.png https://i.sstatic.net/eCcWdsvI.png

@PM2Ring Great! My eyes are not what they used to be - what are their slopes (in cm/sec/day)?

For 2024-Nov, the speed deltas in cm/sec per day for Voy1 range from  -1.875 to -1.869 and Voy2 -2.648 to -2.639

@PM2Ring and I got -1.9 and -2.7 by waving my hands in the air above a spherical cow standing on the back of an envelope! :-)  https://i.sstatic.net/tCeYOq8y.png

And for New Horizons, https://i.sstatic.net/O9KjUoB1.png with deltas -14.096 to -13.994

You can find this information in NASA's Horizons application. Select "Voyager 1" or "Voyager 2" as target and select "Speed wrt Sun & observer" as requested output in the table and a suitable time frame. The column VmagSn is the Sun-relative speed:

'VmagSn      VmagOb' =
Magnitude of target centers' velocity with respect to the Sun ("VmagSn")
and the observer ("VmagOb") at the time light left the target center to be
observed (print time minus down-leg light-time). These are absolute values
of the velocity vectors (total speeds) and do NOT indicate direction of motion.
Units: KM/S

Here is an example output for Voyager 1:
*******************************************************************************
 Date__(UT)__HR:MN          VmagSn      VmagOb
**********************************************
$$SOE
 2024-Dec-05 00:00      16.9210836  16.9211179
 2024-Dec-06 00:00      16.9210830  16.9211175
 2024-Dec-07 00:00      16.9210824  16.9211170
 2024-Dec-08 00:00      16.9210820  16.9211167
 2024-Dec-09 00:00      16.9210815  16.9211163
...

And here for Voyager 2:
*******************************************************************************
 Date__(UT)__HR:MN          VmagSn      VmagOb
**********************************************
$$SOE
 2024-Dec-05 00:00      15.2731878  15.2732031
 2024-Dec-06 00:00      15.2731712  15.2731867
 2024-Dec-07 00:00      15.2731547  15.2731704
 2024-Dec-08 00:00      15.2731384  15.2731543
 2024-Dec-09 00:00      15.2731222  15.2731383 
...

Voyager 1 is losing less than one mm/s per day (0.04 inch/s per day), and Voyager 2 in the order of 1 cm/s per day (about half an inch/s per day).

For the record, that's 0.002 mph per day

Here's a 3 year plot (from Horizons) of the speed of Voyager 1 relative to the Solar System barycentre, with a 7 day timestep. https://i.sstatic.net/2c8CyCM6.png

Why is Voyager 2 slowing down so much faster!>

@Starship Space kraken

@DarthPseudonym Are they also to blame for the random slowing of Pioneer 10 (not accounted for by the sun's gravity)?

@Starship Voyager 2 is closer to the sun than Voyager 1, but not by nearly enough to account for a 10x acceleration difference. I wonder if it has to do with the shape of the orbit - V2's heading more closely aligns with the sun than V1's arcing trajectory. The sun-relative velocity change will be greater the more closely aligned the velocity and acceleration vectors - an object in circular orbit, for example, sees no change whatsoever in sun-relative velocity despite undergoing the exact same acceleration as an object starting from rest at that point.

@Starship Nah, the Pioneer anomaly has been fully explained, it's just the RTG emitting heat non-symmetrically.

@DarthPseudonym, it's not just asymmetric heat emissions from the RTG, it's those emissions reflecting off of the spacecraft, plus thermal emissions from the spacecraft's own heat.  Until computers got powerful enough to model all of those factors, the full anomaly was unexplained.

@NuclearHoagie Voyager 1 is headed almost in the same direction as the Sun. Voyager 2 is headed at a much greater angle away from the Sun's galactic orbit. This will create an illusion of the more angled spacecraft losing speed faster relative to the Sun. The second contributor is that Voyager 2 is traveling slower (~3.1AU/yr) than Voyager 1 (~3.5AU/yr), so it will slow down slightly faster by having slightly less escape energy to begin with. https://public.nrao.edu/ask/where-is-voyager-1-headed-and-when-will-it-get-there/
